# What is the plural of interrogative words (what, who, where, when, how, why, etc.)

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, questions

If interrogative words are used as nouns, how are they pluralized?

**Example:** This will answer your *hows* and *whys*.

What is the correct form?

- whys (the same as most English words?)
- why's (following the rationale of pluralized acronyms?)
- why (they cannot be pluralized?)

Comment: I wouldn't say that these interrogative words are true nouns here, they are in some sense by metonymy shortened forms of "'why' questions", that is, the interrogative word is being quoted, used as a modifier, then the thing modified is dropped.

Comment: @Mitch: It's a moot point whether this usage of *how* is best described as *metonymy, ellipsis*, or something else. But whichever way you look at it, *how* and *why* are functioning as nouns in OP's example, and should thus be pluralised in the normal way, as Irene says.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As in W S Gilbert: 'Never mind the why and wherefore'.

Comment: @Barrie: Because the G&S context is famous, that gets several thousand hits on Google Books. But [the pluralised version](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22Never+mind+the+whys+and+wherefores%22&pbx=1&oq=%22Never+mind+the+whys+and+wherefores%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4297l6109l7l6547l2l2l0l0l0l0l110l204l1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=df29b8ae0d4c27e&biw=1186&bih=816) also gets over 100 hits, none (or at least, very few) of which seem to be related to the HMS Pinafore reference.

Comment: @Mitch: Wonder if a metonymy ceases to be a noun? What would a noun become when 'metonymized', then?

Comment: @Kris: metonymy isn''t about part of speech though it's usual noun to noun. The usage of 'why' etc is certainly as a noun; I guess I was just grumbling that using it as a noun sounds loose and informal in the direction of ungrammatical, giving a grammatical justification for why it might be acceptable. It's used and sounds ok so that's that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are pluralised adding the *-s* at the end of the word: *why/whys*, *how/hows*, etc.

Comment: +1 Right, but ***why***? :)

Comment: @Kris: If you look up the word "why" in Oxford Dictionaries Online, you will see that it is listed as a noun, among other uses. As a noun, it can be pluralised just like any other English noun (as long as it doesn't belong to any particular category that forbids normal pluralisation, that is).

Comment: The plural of *sty* is *sties*; therefore the regular plural of *why* should be *whies*.

Comment: I understand @tchrist to be questioning the part of this answer which says question words have *regular* plurals. In fact if they had regular plurals then the plurals would be *who/whos*, *what/whats*, *where/wheres*, *when/whens*, ***why/whies***, and *how/hows*. Irene wouldn't it make more sense to drop the word "regularly"?

Comment: @tchrist I think you're mistaking the word stye, which make sense why the plural would be what it is.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stye